# Drawing a rectangle over an image where I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have some images in a page, and I want to draw a rectangle in the place where I click to leave it marked. I'm trying to achieve this with a canvas, but I'm not getting anywhere. I can't see the canvas I'm creating anywhere, and of course, not the rectangle either.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
canvas { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    background-color: red;
}   
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('img').click(function(e) {
        $('#output_'+this.id).html('X:'+event.offsetX+' Y:'+event.offsetY);

         if(!this.canvas) {
             this.canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
         }
        var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        ctx.rect(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 3, 3);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fill();
    });

});
</script>
<pre id="output_1"></pre>
<img id="1" src="Desert.jpg" width="200" height="200"></img>
<pre id="output_2"></pre>
<img id="2" src="Hydrangeas.jpg" width="200" height="200"></img>
```

Comment: _I can't see the canvas I'm creating anywhere..._ Because you don't create canvas anywhere. Image != canvas.

Comment: So how could I create a canvas to be exactly on top of every image I click?

Comment: Start from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: It sure looks like I'm creating one. I just printed the value of "ctx" and it is a valid context.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed this line: `this.canvas = $('<canvas />')[0]`. However you don't add this canvas into DOM, so you can't see it.

Comment: I finally solved this using a totally different approach, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944159/loading-multiple-images-into-multiple-canvases

Answer (score 0):

to attach your filled canvas to the html you need to append it. Another thing is how to achieve positioning them at the top of the images. If you need an square, why don't you use border? Use canvas for that task is low-performance, hard-coding and brain-breaking.

### Help 1

Append your canvas:
When you do this:

```
     if(!this.canvas) {
         this.canvas = $('<canvas />')[0];
     }
```

you need to add

```
     $(this.canvas).appendTo($('body'));
```

Where `$('body')` can be the selector of the element that you need to attach.

### Help 2

Make it by a normal method.

```js
$('img').on('click' , function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('with-border');
});
```

```css
.with-border {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x100/000/fff&text=click+me">
```

### EDIT

To put the canvas in absolute positioning where the images are:

```
  var cnvas = $(this.canvas);
  cnvas.appendTo($('body'));
  cnvas.css({
       position: 'absolute',
       left: event.offsetX,
       top: event.offsetY,
       'z-index': 1
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "appendTo" didn't work. Also, what I need is to create a rectangle exactly in the place I clicked on the image, hence the coordinates (offsetX and offsetY).

Comment: Sorry, i update the answer with that `$(this.canvas).appendTo($('body'));`

Comment: Ok, now I can see the canvas. And I can see the rectangles I'm creating on them. Hooray! One thing missing: I need the canvas to be invisible, and created exactly on top of the referred image. Right now it is being created after the two images on my code. Can you help?

Comment: I've edited my awser. See the section called **EDIT**. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. I'm trying to get the coordinates of the image but ran into some troubles with the scroll. I'm trying a new approach, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944159/loading-multiple-images-into-multiple-canvases

Comment: Why don't you make a working fiddle to show us what happens? I don't know why, but the code should work. The canvas is attached to body, and position absolute with left and top based on X|Y axis. Nothing more is needed. Try make a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

you can create canvas without drowimage by make canvas backgound transparent,try this

```js
$(function() {
    $('img').click(function(event) {
     $('#output_'+this.id).html('X:'+event.offsetX+' Y:'+event.offsetY);
      if(this.canvas) return
          var w=this.width
    var h=this.height
   
         if(!this.canvas) {
  
             this.canvas = $('<canvas  />').insertBefore($(this))[0];
         }
   $(this.canvas ).height(h)
    $(this.canvas ).width(w)
        var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  //ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, w  ,h);

        ctx.rect(event.offsetX, event.offsetY, 3,3);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fill();
    });

});
```

```css
canvas { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color: trnaparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<pre id="output_1"></pre>
<img id="1" src="http://dummyimage.com/120x100/000/fff&text=Img 1" width="200" height="200"></img>
<pre id="output_2"></pre>
<img id="2" src="http://dummyimage.com/120x100/000/fff&text=Img 2" width="200" height="100"></img>
```