# Loading multiple images into multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I got a code for loading an image into a canvas, and it works fine, but when I try to iterate to do it multiple times, it only loads one image (the last one). Anyone knows why?

```
<pre id="output_1"></pre>
<canvas id="canvas_1"></canvas>
<pre id="output_2"></pre>
<canvas id="canvas_2"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pics = [ 'Desert.jpg', 'Hydrangeas.jpg' ];
    for(var i=0; i < pics.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        var ctx = $( '#canvas_'+(i+1) )[0].getContext('2d');
        img.onload = function() { 
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };
        img.src = pics[i];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The var `img` is being overwritten as you loop. The `onload`s will not be called until the current execution is complete. By that time img will equal the 3rd iteration.

To fix

```
var pics = [ 'Desert.jpg', 'Hydrangeas.jpg' ];
function loadImage(i){
    var img = new Image();
    var ctx = $( '#canvas_'+(i+1) )[0].getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function() { 
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    img.src = pics[i];
}

for(var i=0; i < pics.length; i++) {
     loadImage(i);
}
```

The call to the function `loadImage` creates a new reference to all the variable each time it is called. It differs from `onload` because it is called immediately, while `onload` is a callback and must wait until the currently executing context has completely exited (in other words returned until there are no more returns), then and only then can the onload happen.